# Time Machine Avoid Full Backup after Clean Install

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, imac

I have an iMac 5K with Mojave 10.14.6. The iMac has an internal SSD and 3 external USB HD drives connected.
All these drives are backupped by Time Machine.
I need to perform a clean install of Catalina on the iMac and I would like to avoid Time Machine to backup all the drives another time.
My Documents on the internal HD are stored on OneDrive.
How can I do?
After clean installation and after restoring documents from one drive may I use tmutil inheritbackup?